# Htop immediately closes on Apple Silicon (MacBook Air M1)

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon, htop

I installed the Homebrew (non rosetta), then installed the htop. Installation process finished successfully, but htop doesn't work. It just get killed on start.

**~ brew config**

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.7.5-138-g2c83ea7
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 2c83ea7339df5ae4d63b0eeb810f638f6d2cc7ca
Last commit: 11 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 677abf931b7846c5ae391cdcaf7e78b5b22286d5
Core tap last commit: 2 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 12.0 build 1200
Git: 2.30.0 => /opt/homebrew/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 11.0.9.1
macOS: 11.1-arm64
CLT: N/A
Xcode: 12.3
Rosetta 2: false
```

**Trying to run htop:**

```
~: htop
[1]    98691 killed     htop
~:
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Just tried on my Mojave machine, works perfectly fine. Can you post `brew doctor` for me? Thanks!

Comment: @chenrui thanks for the help! brew doctor returns `Your system is ready to brew.`, I tried to reinstall htop, but result is the same.

Comment: My problem was in incorrect installation of Homebrew. I removed and installed brew and issue is gone.